# Issue with adding images: Name of image showing

Tags: graphics

When I add images using the following code

```
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{images/CACPSP}
        \caption{Conductivity of SDS at fixed concentration of NaCl and PEO}
        \label{fig:cacpsp}
    \end{figure}
```

I am getting the following output [image]
The image is present in my images/ folder and I don't know what to do now. I have tried compiling it using texstudio and overleaf but am still getting the same issue

Comment: This means you probably have `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` in your preamble. Remove the `[draft]` part and the image will show. Or indeed as @Zarko commented the option can be given to the documentclass, which then propagates it to all packages that have this option (such as `graphicx`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to completes small document with your figure, which we can test as it is. It seems that you have`draft` option for `\documentclass`.

Comment: Note that in addition to `draft` given as option to `graphicx` it can also have been given as an option to the class your are using (of which you provide no information)